# Valmerge google script not working for shared collaborators

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been using valmerge google apps script with my team. We have been using it in a common google spreadsheet. But abruptly they are not able to run the script. It gives an error "you are not authorised". Whereas when I tried to share the same doc with other email addresses it  worked fine for them.

What could be an issue that only on couple of email addresses it is giving an authentication issue and not on others ?

Any pointer is greatly appreciated..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2608) I have opened recently. Please take a look and "star" it to keep track of updates and kind of vote for it.